# What will happen if I delete the gps.conf file

Tags: android, configuration, gps, supl

What will happen if I delete the `system/etc/gps.conf` file? Does it cause phone to not work? or affect only the GPS related apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What will happen if I delete the system/etc/gps.conf file?

It depends on the handsets / OEM. Some chipsets don't even use the gps.conf file. This config file does not *have* to be in that folder. I know because I've worked on many GPS chipsets.

> Does it cause phone to not work?

Depending on the OEM's code, yeah the phone can crash at boot, if this file does not exists. I think that the OEM should handle this rare case. GPS runs in the `system_server` process. Crashing that is not good.

> or affect only the GPS related apps?

If the phone manages to boot, depending on the information stored in that file, you may not be able to get a GPS fix. One of the more important settings you are likely to find in the conf file is the SUPL settings. SUPL servers are used to pass assisted data so that the GPS fix can be attained quickly. Deleting this file can cause the GPS mode to go to the Standalone mode, which is painfully slow. (Some phones won't even bother to go to the Standalone mode and you never get a fix.)

```
################################
##### AGPS server settings #####
################################

# FOR SUPL SUPPORT, set the following
# SUPL_HOST=supl.host.com or IP
# SUPL_PORT=1234
# Add Google SUPL server and port for Huawei(FB0.B-3409)
SUPL_HOST=supl.google.com
SUPL_PORT=7276
```

---

The moral of this story is always back up the gps.conf file before deleting/modifying it.

Comment: I've been searching a lot about this file, finally seems that I found someone with good knowledge about this XD, so here I go: What's the purpose of the NTP servers settings? Why tweaking them can improve performance? (Or it is more about TTFF?)

Comment: Em, sometimes there are drift errors and dilution in time precision in the time keeping in GPS receivers. Getting a proper GPS fix all depends on high precision of time keeping. That is why NTP servers are used to correct time errors. Read more about [Time Synchronization using NTP here](http://www.akadia.com/services/ntp_synchronize.html). Yes, using faster or server more local to you will result in a faster TTFF.

Comment: My answer is a little outdated. As I know, most GNSS Developers are slowly getting rid of the conf file. At least I did ...  in favour of a better way of configuration customizations.